# Appending data to a table created from an Avro file in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, avro

Every morning, an automatic job creates a new table from an Avro file. In the afternoon, I would need to append some data to this table from a Query.

When trying to do so, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid schema update. Field chn has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE
```

I noticed that I can change the property of the field `chn` from `REQUIRED` to `NULLABLE` in the BigQuery Web UI and then it works fine, but I would have to do it manually everyday which is not what I am looking for.

Is there a way to "cast" the field as `REQUIRED` during the append query ?

Or during the first import from the Avro file, force the field to be `NULLABLE` and not `REQUIRED` ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature that allows relaxing a field as part of a query or a load job will be available in production shortly. I will update this answer when it goes live (likely within a week).

Update: 08/25/2016

You can supply schemaUpdateOptions in load or query job configuration.
Multiple options can be provided.
It allows the schema of the destination table to be updated as a side effect of the load or query job. Schema update options are supported in two cases:

When writeDisposition is `WRITE_APPEND`

When writeDisposition is `WRITE_TRUNCATE` and the destination table is a partition of a table, specified by partition decorators
For non-partitioned tables, `WRITE_TRUNCATE` will always overwrite the schema.

The following values are supported:

`ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION`: allow adding a nullable field to the schema

`ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION`: allow relaxing a required field in the original schema to nullable

NOTE: This doesn't currently work with schema auto-detection. We plan to support that soon.

Comment: The change is live, but we are working through some documentation issues. I will update this post with more details on how to use it shortly

Comment: Since the documentation may take some more time to come out, I updated the answer with a short explanation of how to use the options.